# Super sophisticated AI spacecraft autopilot saves the day

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, spaceship, artificial-intelligence

Looking for the title of this rather excellent sci-fi short story...

- Human spacecraft approaches alien planet
- Humans piloting the spacecraft about to do something inappropriate, given apparent hostile alien action from surface of planet
- Autopilot takes over, aggressively, and moves spacecraft clear of oncoming danger, accelerating the vehicle so as to knock people into their seats, not fire on the aliens, and generally saves the day
- Story told in the few milliseconds that it takes the autopilot to figure all this out, and to take action
- Humans figure it all out, much later, and after the fact.